# How can I choose the type of function I'm going to use in Builder class?

Tags: java, android, builder

I have a method that I use it for sending all my requests to the Server.
And in this method I'm using of Builder class.
I just want to know how can I specify the type of Builder's function by "if" in each request according to the inputs of the function.
here is my function:

```
public String sendHttpRequest(String url, String parameters,String type) {

    try {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, parameters);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()

                .url(url)

                /*what I'm going to do is somthing like this:

                if(type.equal("get")){
                .get()
                 }
                 if(type.equal("post")){
                .post()
                 }
                 */
                .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string().toString();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    return "";
}
```

So what should I do?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use builders either by chaining or separately.

You can try something like this:

```
Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
        .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
if(type.equals("get")){
    builder.get();
} else if(type.equals("post")){
    builder.post(/*body*/);
}
Request request = builder.build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: That was great! Thanks Nabin:)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this OkHttp lib, but since it's a builder, I guess you can create it in parts, before call the build() method. Something like:

```
Request.Builder builder  = new Request.Builder();
builder.url(url)
if(type.equal("get")){
    builder.get();
}
if(type.equal("post")){
    builder.post();
}
builder.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
builder.addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

Request request = builder.build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```